# Would creating an LGBTQ tag make sense?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, specific-tag, tag-usage-guidance

I'm thinking about creating an LGBTQ (Lesbian, Gay, Bisexual, Transgender, Queer/Questioning) tag. I've spotted a few questions so far where it would apply and I suspect we'll have more in the future.

Would such a tag be useful?

Any suggestions for usage guidance?

Potential examples:

[How do I avoid / minimise hurtful reactions when revealing information at work?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/how-do-i-avoid-hurtful-reactions-when-revealing-information-at-work)

[How can I ask politely about someone's preferred gender pronouns?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/how-can-i-ask-politely-about-someones-preferred-gender-pronouns)

---

I've created the [lgbt+](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt%2b) the excerpt is a work in progress, so feel free to tweak it as needed.

Comment: LInks to a few examples might help

Comment: We'd also want to be really clear about when this tag is appropriate in the excerpt...

Comment: @Catija I wasn't planning on going around applying it to other people's questions without asking first. More thinking that if it was available people would probably use it.

Comment: That wasn't what I meant. People are occasionally overly... taggy. They want **all the tags**... so if they ask a question and happen to identify as LGBTQ, even if the question doesn't relate to it, they may use that tag... so the tag excerpt needs to emphasize that we should only use the tag as intended.

Comment: @Catija any suggestions on how to word that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it could be helpful for categorization, yes. This is information that will almost certainly be included in the question if it is relevant, but tags do make it easy to search for types of questions; members of the LGBTQ community would likely find such a tag useful.

Suggestions for usage:

**Do** use this tag

- When a question is about issues of sexual orientation pertaining to the LGBTQ community.
- When one person in a given interaction is a part of the LGBTQ community *and this is relevant to the question*.

**Don't** use this tag

- When one person involved happens to be a member of the LGBTQ community, but this is not relevant to the question.

I think that we should be careful about what we call this tag. I know that "LGBT", "LGBTQ", "LGBTQ+" and other terms are often used by people who identify as a member of those groups. We need to make sure that the name isn't accidentally exclusive of anybody - or, more importantly, that it's a commonly-recognized term.

Comment: I would say LGBT+ or LGBTQ+ would be the best options, as they are inclusive of other identities.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 sadly I don't think that + is allowed in tags.

Comment: @Avery We can, and [the current tag](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt%2b) has one.

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to this area of stack overflow, so I can't comment as to whether a tag of this sort would be overused.
That being said, I can think of many specific questions that can be asked that would be specific ( "how do i tell them I'm gay / a different gender" ) where this would apply and potentially useful. And many more questions that relate to different groups within the LGBT community.

EDIT.
just to add ( and in relation to the other answer posted) I think we need to be careful when judging whether the tag relates to the question or not, where from a hetereonormative point of view these may only be adjacent to the question itself, yet may actually be central to the point - or at least of particular interest to those in the LGBT+ communities.
a good example of this might be a question where the OP might ask a question along the lines of "I've recently PreP, who should I tell?".

In addition i'd say that the use of the tag be questioned in a comment before being removed - eg. in a question along the lines of "I'm in a heterosexual relationship - how do I....",may seem like there is no need for the tag. The fact the OP may be bisexual (and may not have stated such) might actually effect the question, and require the question to be edited rather than the tag removed.

In regards to which choice of letter to use, I'd have suggested LGBT+ , frankly there is always someone who'll complain that there are too many/not enough letters. Surely an explanation on a wiki page stating that the letters choosen when the best attempt at a choice that was always going to be problematic

Comment: Would you mind if I added the tag to your question?

Comment: @apaul34208 not at all, its broadly applicable to my question